# ¿Como connectar con IP publica a mikrotik api? Al subirlo al servidor manda un error y localmente funciona bien con la ip publica

Tags: php

!Este es el error que me surge al intentar conectar desde el servidor en la nube
Cuando lo pruebo localmente funciona sin ningun problema. ¿Debo configurar algo más en mi mikrotik?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí].com/DfGSh.png

Comment: Por favor, no pongas el código como foto, dificulta mucho el poder ayudarte. El error te indica que, por algún motivo, no ha podido abrir el archivo, y al fwrite le ha llegado un false(en lugar del recurso, el archivo). Mira si el archivo existe en la ruta, y si tiene permisos de lectura/escritura.